# How to load an image(1) based on filename stored in MySQL database into Android App

Tags: android

So, I have an Android app that is essentially a `ListView`(**MainActivity**, `fill_parent`). And details activity(**DetailsActivity**) with a bunch of `TextViews` for **Name**, **Phone** and **Email**.

You tap on a list item in **MainActivity** to initiate the **DetailsActivity** to see more info about the selected item from the list.

There's a **MySQL** database with one table that contains **ID**, **Name**, **Phone**, **Email** and **Image** columns for each person. **Image** column is just a `VARCHAR` that contains filename of the appropriate image to every record.

Between database and android app is **PHP** webservice. It's used to get all persons(**get_all.php**, for the `ListView` to be populated) and also get detailed information(**get_details.php**) about a particular person based on **ID** passed to it(populates `DetailsActivity`).

I assume `ImageView` widget(DetailsActivity layout) will have to be used to display the images, so that's not a problem.

Problem I'm stuck at is where should I store the actual images in order to pull them into the app when `DetailsActivity` is started for a person?

Answer (score 0):

You should use cache your pictures to SDCard.

Here is a great lib that will help you to achieve it:

http://androidimageloader.com/

So, you will have all your thumbnails on your SDCard.

When you will open the DetailActivity, that's the time when you will copy the full size picture on SDCard.

Comment: Good idea, but where should I store the images outside of the app? So that I can load/cache them into the app.

Comment: Pictures are loaded on SDCard with this ;-) I guess you will have to load the thumbnails and when loading the detailActivity, then download the big sized picture!

Comment: I don't use thumbnails. My list items just have TextView layout with the Name of the person. It's when I click on that list item the image should load. I understand what you mean by sotring an image when retrieving it, but where should I download the images from?

Comment: On the start of DetailActivity, launch a thread or asynctask that download the picture on SDcard and at the end, display it.. What is complicated????

Comment: But where do I download the picture FROM?

Comment: "Image column is just a VARCHAR that contains filename of the appropriate image to every record."=> "http://yourdomain.com/pics/"+image+".jpg" ???